Can we sequentially rotate a die on 3 axes from a given starting position so that the result is uniform?
Edit
It seems that my initial assumption that the rotations in question occur simultaneously was wrong. They are calculated sequentially but animated simultaneously. Therefore I have updated the question accordingly.
Problem description
We have a classic 6-sided die. We sequentially rotate it on 3 axes by 3 random numbers and the last result is the starting position. I'd like to know if by such rotation we can generate a new result that is uniform.

In detail

We have a function rand that returns a uniform integer for a given range

For each axis (x, y, z) we randomly generate a new number and rotate the die on a given axis by this number multiplied by π/2 (there are 4 sides per axis)

We rotate the die sequentially on each axis. Here is the link to the documentation about the Euler angles that are used in rotations



The order of components in this vector matches the axes of rotation:
Pitch (the x component) is the rotation about the node’s x-axis.
Yaw (the y component) is the rotation about the node’s y-axis.
Roll (the z component) is the rotation about the node’s z-axis.
SceneKit applies these rotations relative to the node’s pivot property in the reverse order of the components: first roll, then yaw, then pitch.


The last result is the starting position

The question is whether following the above requirements we can generate a new number with a uniform distribution?
For example it seems that if I generate a random number for each axis from range 1 ≤ n ≤ 4 the result is slightly biased in favor of the starting position. I suspect that the starting position influences the calculations but I can't seem to overcome this issue. Is this problem solvable with the given requirements? Or maybe my approach is fundamentally wrong?
Function example
I'm using a function that is documented as:

Creates an action that rotates the node by a relative value in radian.

Below is a example what happens when I rotate the die on each axis by numbers 2, 1 and 0:
https://s9.gifyu.com/images/SZk3w.gif
SCNAction.rotateBy(
    x: .pi / 2 * 2,
    y: .pi / 2 * 1,
    z: .pi / 2 * 0,
    duration: .ultraSlow
)

And here's the code to the first animation (top of the question):
SCNAction.rotateBy(
    x: .pi / 2 * Int.random(in: 4 ... 7),
    y: .pi / 2 * Int.random(in: 4 ... 7),
    z: .pi / 2 * Int.random(in: 4 ... 7),
    duration: .ultraSlow
)

Alternative solution
Browsing the documentation I actually found another function that rotates the die to an absolute angle. This means that I can simply generate a random number from 1 ≤ n ≤ 6 and rotate to a pre-calculated angle that corresponds to that number.
However, for my own curiosity (and for the sake of others that may find this question) I'm still interested in knowing the answer to my problem.

can you give a formula for where the points of the cube are during such a simultaneous rotation? There are well known formulae for position when rotating around a single axis but it is hard (for me at least) to see what such a "simultaneous rotation" is doing at a given instant.

Hi, welcome to MSE! I am also not totally sure what you mean by simultaneously rotating about several axes. I also don't understand what the bullet point "the last result is the starting position" means. It sounds like you've already written some code or done some calculations in the case of uniformly chosen integers in ${1, 2, 3, 4}$. If so, there's no harm in including that in your post (possibly as a link)! This might make it easier to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Thanks for your comments, that is actually an issue that I don't exactly know how the die rotates simultaneously. I've attached a slowed down example and some code. I hope it will help a bit.

The illustration with the six-sided die is not the best illustration of the rotation because even at "ultraSlow" speed it's hard to keep track of which corner went where each time the rotation code runs. A better illustration of the rotation would be simply to tell us what the coordinates of the eight corners of the cube are at the start, pick a corner, give the list of the next four locations of that corner under the next four rotations, and then do the same for one more corner. I am not sure, but I think the rotations use body axes.

I think I have tracked two of the faces in the "ultraslow" example, which is enough to define the rotations. We start with the 1 fact in front (facing the viewer) and the 5 face on top. On the first rotation, 1 goes to the left face (from the viewer's point of view) and 5 goes to the bottom. Then 1 goes to the back face and 5 goes to the top. Then 1 becomes the right face and 5 is on the bottom. Then return to the starting position.

I am not familiar with this type of 3D animation and the conventions therein and I am unable to do any testing. I haven't been able to make sense of the documentation here, but do you think it's possible that x, y and z refer to Euler angles, presumably with this convention? If so then it's not really simultaneous rotations, but three sequential rotations being animated "directly".

@IzaakvanDongen Yes, I believe you're right - I was mislead by the animation. It seems that indeed we're referring to Euler angles and that the rotations happen sequentially. I shall edit the question.

Even with the added documentation I cannot make sense of how the rotations are defined. Neither the standard body-centric nor world-centric applications of the rotation axes seem to work. The only thing I've been able to guess so far that matches the observed rotations is that the "state" of the object includes a set of Euler/Tait-Bryan angles representing the total rotation that the object has undergone since the instant it was created, and that SCNAction.rotateBy adds numeric values to those respective angles. Also doing yaw between pitch and roll is weird.
